# Update isn't working using with clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, insert-update, postgresql-9.6

```
WITH first_insert AS 
(
    INSERT INTO first_insert_table (column_of_first_insert_table) 
    VALUES (10) 
    RETURNING first_insert_table_id
),
second_insert AS 
(
    INSERT INTO second_insert_table(column_of_second_insert_table)
    VALUES((SELECT * FROM first_insert)) 
    RETURNING second_insert_table_id
)  
--here doesn't update column_of_first_insert_table!
UPDATE first_insert_table 
SET column_of_first_insert_table = column_of_first_insert_table + 1
WHERE first_insert_table_id = (SELECT * FROM first_insert) ;
```

Why doesn't this query update `column_of_first_insert_table` column of `first_insert_table`, when I try to update `first_insert_table` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't perform the expected update is for the same reason why this simplified version of your example will not show the row being inserted in the `WITH` clause:

```
with cte as (
  insert into first_insert_table (column_of_first_insert_table)
  values (10)
)
select * from first_insert_table
```

When executing the above statement, the `INSERT` does happen successfully, but the `SELECT` portion of the statement does not *see* it, because the `SELECT` only sees the data that existed at the moment the statement began executing.

The same is happening in your example. The `WHERE` clause of your `UPDATE` can only find rows that existed at the moment the whole statement began, so it doesn't see the row that was inserted in the `WITH` clause.

This behavior is documented ([7.8.2. Data-Modifying Statements in `WITH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)):

> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. **All the statements are executed with the same *snapshot* (see Chapter 13), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables.** This alleviates the effects of the unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that `RETURNING` data is the only way to communicate changes between different `WITH` sub-statements and the main query.